# How to share some page details as a link in developed real time chat application

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, uicollectionview, google-cloud-firestore

I am developing an `IOS` app. In my app, I developed a real-time chat application with a firestore database. I am sending messages and images in my chat application. Now I would like to share some of the details pages through button click in that page as a link in real time chat which I developed in my app. Is it possible? If so please let me know. Thanks in advance.

My chat application created without a `storyboard`. It is a collection view.

// appending data to cell

```
override func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {

let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! ChatMessageCell

let messages = mes[indexPath.item]
cell.textView.text = mes[indexPath.item].Text

if(messages.SenderId == uid){
    cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(hexStr: "#007AFF")
    cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.white
    cell.profileImageView.isHidden = true
    cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = false
    cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = true
} else {
    cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.colorWithHexString(hexStr: "#D3D3D3")
    cell.textView.textColor = UIColor.black
    cell.profileImageView.isHidden = false
    cell.bubbleLeftAnchor?.isActive = true
    cell.bubbleRightAnchor?.isActive = false
}

let image = messages.ImageURL
if image != nil && image != ""{
    cell.messageImageView.loadImageUsingCacheWithUrlString(image!)
    cell.messageImageView.isHidden = false
    cell.bubbleView.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
}
else {
    cell.messageImageView.isHidden = true
}

//lets modify width of the textview here somehow
if messages.Text != nil  && messages.Text != "" {
    cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = estimatedFrameForText(text: messages.Text!).width + 32
    cell.textView.isHidden = false
}
else if messages.ImageURL != nil && messages.ImageURL != ""{
    cell.bubbleWidthAnchor?.constant = 200
    cell.textView.isHidden = true
}

return cell
}
```

Comment: To send a link to a specific location in your app to other users who may or may not have the app installed, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/dynamic-links

Comment: I'm would say this question is very vague; I got you've developed and app, and a chat system within the app but *Now I would like to share some of the details page* is unclear; what's a details page? Is this a master/detail app and you want to share an objects details with another user? If so, send them the key to the master object and they can then tap it an open it in their own app. If not, the question needs a lot of work to be understandable.